# How to block parent job until both the downstream jobs are completed

Tags: jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ85u.png)I have 4 jobs(Job A, B, C and D), where Job A triggers B,C and D as downstream projects.
B and C should run in parallel and A must wait until both the jobs are completed.
Based on the result(Fail/unstable) of Job C, Job D needs to be triggered(regardless the status of Job B).
Please suggest how to create this type of job.

I have tried "Trigger/call builds on other projects" twice for both the jobs B and C and I selected "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" for one job, for example C.
In this case, Job A completes immediately once Job C is completed though Job B is still ongoing.
I tried "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" for both B and C, in this case both B and C did not started in parallel, Job C waited until Job B is finished. I need both B and C to be triggered in parallel and Job A should wait until B, C, D(if C is failed) are finished.

NA

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some code samples of the solutions that you have attempted - this will make it easier to provide solutions.

Comment: Please find the attached screen-shot.

Comment: so if I try like the attached image, Job A will be completed once Job C is completed even if job B is ongoing. I want to block Job A until job B is finished.
If I block Job B then Job C will not be started until Job B is finished.. I want both B and C to be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by defining job B and C in the same "Projects to build section" under "Build Triggers" seperated by comma and "blocked until the triggered project finish their builds".